# PHP FFmpeg conversion issues for mp4 files

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I want to get the images out of a `mp4` file by using `ffmpeg-php`.

I have

```
 $str_command= '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /test/ts.mp4 -r 1 -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:01 -s 300x300 -f image2 /test/images/';
 shell_exec($str_command);
```

However, I got an error message saying

```
 Buffering several frames is not supported. Please consume all available frames before adding a new one.
```

I have spent hours on web but couldn't find the answer for this. Can anyone help me about this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked out the ffmpeg library for PHP? I've worked with it before and it abstracts away all of the complicated command line calls like the one you're trying to run. You can use $movie->getFrame($n) to get the frame object, and $frame->toGDImage() to output it as an image.

For example,

```
$movie = new ffmpeg('/path/to/movie.mp4');
$frame10 = $movie->getFrame(10);
$image = $frame10->toGDImage();

// Now display the image
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($image);

// Or save it to a file
$saved = imagejpeg($image, '/path/to/new/file.jpg');
```

Check out the documentation at http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/doc/api/

Comment: I did read it but it didn't occur to me that this might be the solution. I was lead to believe this can only be done by shell command.

Comment: Just make sure you also have the GD library installed.